# Save Alasql instance to file

Tags: serialization, alasql

Is it possible to serialize/save to filesystem an instance of alasql db? Currently,docs says it can read but not write to sqlite file.

Comment: AlaSQL 0.2.6 still does not support exporting/importing the full state